# UICollectionView doesn't update immediately after CATransition animation

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, uicollectionview, catransition

I want create push animation for UICollectionView to move from one folder to another.

Doing so:

```
CATransition *transition = [CATransition animation];
    transition.duration = 0.3;
    transition.fillMode = kCAFillModeRemoved;
    [transition setTimingFunction:[CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionDefault]];
    transition.type = kCATransitionMoveIn;
    transition.subtype = kCATransitionFromRight;
    transition.delegate = self;
[FileNameGridView.layer addAnimation:transition forKey:nil];
[FileNameGridView reloadData];
```

But UICollectionView doesn't update immediately.

[Here's an record from the screen to better understand what the problem is.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Tm66HCUhZYA&feature=youtu.be)

Any ideas?

Comment: The way the images pop into place makes it look like you code is not running on the main thread. Any possibility your code is running on a background thread?

Comment: Code for image load running in main thread.

Comment: Dunno if you got your answer already, but try calling reloadData before adding the transition.